# How to map Prisma enum to a TS enum type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, prisma

How can I map my auto generated Prisma enums to my GraphQL / Typescript enum?

I have an enum to list my supported currencies in my app like so:

```
enum Currency {
  GBP
  USD
}
```

Prisma then generates my PrismaClient and types for me and converts these enums to a type instead of a TS enum:

```
export const Currency: {
  GBP: 'GBP',
  USD: 'USD'
};

export type Currency = (typeof Currency)[keyof typeof Currency]
```

This causes issues as I have a GraphQL schema which defines my currencies like so and using codegen, it converts them to a TS enum:

```
// GQL Schema
enum Currency {
  GBP
  USD
}

// TS output 
export enum Currency {
  GBP = 'GBP',
  USD = 'USD'
}
```

This means when my query resolver tries to fetch currencies from Prisma, the return type doesn't match the expected GQL types.

Can I tell Prisma to convert enums to a TS enum (instead of the TS type)?

Is there a way to map one type to another using codegen mappers or something similar?

Proposed solution:
I think I have got something working, albeit not sure it's the best approach.

I have updated my codegen config to use a custom mapper:

```
schema: "./src/typeDefs/index.ts"
generates:
  ./src/types.d.ts:
    config:
      useIndexSignature: true
      namingConvention:
        enumValues: keep
      scalars:
        UUID: string
        Decimal: Decimal
        DateTime: Date
      mappers:
        Product: ./interfaces/index.ts#Product // This product type has my currency enum
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
      - add:
          content: "import Decimal from 'decimal.js'"
require:
  - tsconfig-paths/register
```

```
// custom type to override
import Prisma from "@prisma/client";

export interface Product extends Omit<Prisma.Product, "currency"> {
  currency: Prisma.Currency;
}
```

I don't know why overriding the `currency` and setting back to its original value seems to make it work though. I will keep digging

Comment: Why not change your GraphQL codegen to generate union types?

Comment: *"Prisma then generates my PrismaClient and types for me..."* Pardon my Prisma ignorance, but does Prisma take the `enum` you've shown at the top of your question as an input to that process, or does it get its information elsewhere? Because if it doesn't, you could just use the Prisma type instead of the enum...

Comment: I'm presuming the GraphQL type is generated from a schema? Are you using Apollo? If not, just do what T.J. Crowder says above

Comment: Prisma takes the enum at the top from it's own schema definition. The GQL type is generated the the GQL schema and all matches up perfectly except for enums

Comment: > could just use the Prisma type instead of the enum. My GraphQL response types expect to match my GraphQL schema. There needs to be mapping from the datasource to the output